# Здравствуйте, здесь правильно расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Рядовой зритель, конечно же, схавает. А тот, кто видел и читал все эти истории, энное кол-во раз, скорее срыгнет, чем будет в восторге.

Comment: После слова _истории_ запятая не нужна.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ответ и расскажите, почему не нужна запятая. Грамматика или правило, что-нибудь.

Comment: Прекрасная фраза, ничего не нужно исправлять, а то испортите, отправляйте прямо так!

Comment: @Буратино А запятая-то зачем после слова "истории"? Почему обособляем оборот?

Comment: @Sharon ну это как там называется, придаточное? когда информация дополнительная к основной, её можно обособить. То есть не видел и читал энное, а (уже) видел и читал истории, (причем) энное количество раз. Вообще критерий подсчета энного не указан, и может это относится к рыганию энного количества раз: энное количество раз срыгнёт.

Comment: @Буратино  Нет, здесь по структуре предложения возможен только уточняющий оборот: (причем) энное кол-во раз. Может этот оборот быть уточняющим?

Comment: Я думаю, что можно произнести в трех вариантах - обособление справа, слева или полное(уточняющий оборот). Но на ценности высказывания это никак не отражается)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего написать так:

> Рядовой зритель, конечно же, схавает, а тот, кто видел и читал все эти истории энное количество раз, скорее срыгнет, чем будет в восторге.

- Запятая перед "энное" не нужна, ведь кто-то "видел и читал истории" какое-то количество раз, а не "срыгивал".
- Точка перед "А" тоже не нужна, так как это не начало нового предложения, а продолжение предыдущего.