# Нужна ли запятая? Сомневаюся я всегда

Tags: запятые

> Речь есть ресурс, которым мы можем самые разнообразные, непередаваемые ни в какой переписке (,) чувства изображать и передавать.

Comment: Эта тема есть в правилах Розенталя, предложите свой вариант решения.

Comment: Может, это шифровка какая? Или розыгрыш? Я уж и не знаю)  А мы здесь все "хаваем", как в вопросе https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478451/Здравствуйте-здесь-правильно-расставлены-знаки-препинания

Comment: Длинную фразу не надо превращать в тему вопроса, вопроса об одной запятой.

Comment: Вам мой ответ подходит? Вы никак на него не отреагировали. Меня интересует не принятие ответа, а ваше понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Передаваемые* в данном случае причастие, а не прилагательное, потому что употреблено именно в глагольном значении — значении 'передавать что-то'. А следовательно, пишем с НЕ раздельно (есть зависимые слова):

*Речь есть ресурс, которым мы можем самые разнообразные, не передаваемые ни в какой переписке чувства изображать и передавать*.

Запятая не нужна, поскольку причастный оборот стоит до определяемого слова и не имеет значения уточнения; оба определения однородны.

Comment: Максим, дайте ссылку на правило.  Можно ди оборот рассматривать как дополнительную информацию и на этом основании обособить? Или это нельзя сделать ни в коем случае? Но почему же тогда автор вопрос сомневается?

Comment: @Sharon А смысл в этой запятой? Кто это будет обособлять для дополнительной информации? В этом обособлении нет смысла. Этих знаков вполне достаточно.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на правило, или вам нужно подсказывать, где ее найти?  ПАС или Розенталь.

Comment: Как вам, кстати, стилистики и семантика предложения?  О чем там вообще-то говорится?) Передавать и непередаваемый – это тавтология или средство худ. выразительности?

Comment: Почему  разделено на части сказуемое "можем изображать и передавать"? Вот как работать с таким предложением?

Answer (score 2):

Леопольд, ты извини, но ты вроде опытный, так что я тебе один умный вещь скажу, ты только не обижайся.

Мне кажется, проблем в фразе куда больше, чем одна запятая: непередаваемые передавать - чересчур литературненько. Ещё и "непередаваемые в переписке и речь", ничего что письмо - тоже речь, только письменная? Ну а "речь есть ресурс(??)... которым можем передавать(!?)" - это в анналы мемов сразу.

Предположу, что ты что-то такое хотел нацарапкать?

Недаром говорят, бумага всё стерпит, однако, только с помощью устной речи можно передавать самые сложные и разнообразные человеческие чувства, которые в конверт не вложить и в письме не отправить.