# Нужна ли запятая: разнообразные(,) не передаваемые ни в какой переписке чувства?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, определения, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Сочетание взято из **[темы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478453/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0),** которая недавно обсуждалась на форуме: ***разнообразные, не передаваемые ни в какой переписке** чувства.*

Обсуждалась вторая запятая, а **первая** была поставлена: в ответе отношения были названы **однородными**.

А вот что в них однородного, ведь семантика явно **разная**. Так почему ставится эта **запятая?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***разнообразные, не передаваемые ни в какой переписке** чувства*

Запятая ставится не только по формальным признакам (одиночное определение-прилагательное, причастный оборот), но и по семантике.
Определения близки по **сходству производимого ими впечатления** (об этом указано в 3-м подпункте 1-го пункта [параграфа Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98&ysclid=lr2cuwy0j7827242013)).
Оба определения вызывают положительные эмоции, связанные с чем-то незаурядным, глубоким, фантазийным...

Comment: Да, спасибо. Вы очень интересно  определили тему для сближения признаков, а это именно семантика.  Единые синтаксические функции ряда, как я думаю, определяются его семантическим единством. Вот некоторые цитаты из теории. В предложении однородные члены объединяются в цельный структурно-семантический блок по отношению к другим членам предложения.  Однородные члены выступают не сами по себе, а лишь в структурно-семантическом единстве.  Поэтому я принимаю именно ваш ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> А вот что в них однородного, ведь семантика явно **разная**. Так почему ставится эта **запятая**?

**См. справочник Розенталя:**

> **§ 10. Однородные и неоднородные определения**
>
> 1. Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится **запятая**.
>
> **Согласованные определения являются однородными:**
>
> <…>
>
> 7. **если за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом**: *малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; древняя, почерневшая от времени деревянная статуэтка; небольшое, устланное коврами возвышение; чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы; худое, изборождённое глубокими морщинами лицо; пустое; запорошенное снегом поле; ранняя, чуть заигравшая зорька; твёрдый, плохо выбритый подбородок* (ср. при другом порядке слов: *плохо выбритый твёрдый подбородок*).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98&ysclid=lr2cuwy0j7827242013

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я хорошо знаю этот материл. Как раз сегодня смотрела, когда тема обсуждалась (и ссылка у меня была),  поэтому и вопрос задала. Наш вариант подходит под это правило, но вопрос-то остается. Почему по Розенталю мы должны считать эти определения однородными, если семантика разная. Если это сближение, то на каком основании?

Answer (score 2):

Семантика ни при чём.

> Однородными членами предложения называют такие члены предложения,
> которые **отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и относятся к одному и тому
> же слову**. Однородными могут быть как главные, так и второстепенные
> члены предложения. Однородные члены предложения не зависят друг от
> друга, они связаны интонацией перечисления.

А запятая, потому что у нас прилагательное и причастный (страдательный до слёз) оборот.

---

(Второй же запятой не может быть как класса: оба определения взывают к чувствам. То есть причастный оборот не служит уточнением к прилагательному. Вот если бы да - то ДА.)

Comment: Спасибо! Мне жаль, что наши точки зрения на этот раз не совпали)

Answer (score 1):

**О СЕМАНТИКЕ**

Еще раз спасибо Александру за его прекрасный ответ, который разрешил многие мои сомнения. Кроме того, сам момент был интересен. Я всегда считала, что однородные члены не только грамматически, но и **семантически** связаны между собой.

Вот Кустова определяет **тип отношений** между однородными членами (а это **семантика**!). Основные **виды**: соединительные, разделительные, противительные, градационные.

Но такие отношения возможны между **лексически сопоставимыми** словами, и это тоже семантика. Мы вообще не могли бы составлять однородные ряды, если бы не знали  **смысловое значение** этих слов.

Еще интересный **пример**: обычно для однородного ряда можно подобрать **обобщающее слово**, а это значит, что члены ряда независимо друг от друга раскрывают какую-то общую тему. Так, при сближения значений для однородных определений мы называем эту тему, например: *темная, безлунная ночь*, сближение признаков по причинно-следственной связи.

**ОСНОВНАЯ ЧАСТЬ**

Речь пойдет **о формальных признаках однородности** (всегда ли они соблюдаются).

1. **Структурные** особенности вариантов (определение + оборот  или оборот + определение) считаются формальными **признаками** для однородности или неоднородности.

Эти структурные особенности задают удобное прочтение фразы (**с перечислением или без перечисления**). У Розенталя:   *твЁрдый, плохо выбритый подборОдок* (ср. при другом порядке слов: *плохо выбритый твёрдый подборОдок).*

2. В то же время **исключения** могут быть в обоих случаях. В частности, на это указывает Розенталь в своих примерах (вариант определение + оборот считается **неоднородным**): ***чёрные** появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; **большой** собранный автором материал* и т. п.

Но эти примеры в любых вариантах **сохраняют неоднородность**: заячий потертый воротник, наполовину потертый заячий воротник.

3. Возьмем пример с **однородными** определениями:  *Стояла **тёмная, безлунная** ночь.* Добавим пояснительные слова:  *Стояла **непривычно тёмная, безлунная** ночь*. Мы видим, что однородные отношения скорее сохраняются, хотя по структуре это  оборот + определение.
4. Таким образом, **формальные** признаки обычно соблюдаются в **базовом/частотном** варианте, но **исключения** возможны.  **Явно** неоднородные признаки однородными **не сделаешь** и наоборот.